# Condenser Microphone Without Phantom Power - Constant Noise

Tags: microphone, recording, power, phantom

Condenser Microphone > XLR Cable > USB Soundcard > Computer

I haven't connected a phantom power, it records well but there is a constant
noise/static in the background.

Please help, how do I get rid of that and have a clean, clear recording experience. This persists in every software, I've tried Windows Recorder, FL Studio.

This is the noise > https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lXNCuO05fz-aBTUVX-gqyTVq0q_sjQRJ

Please help.

Comment: It would help us a lot to know what the mic is - it usually turns out to be one of these... https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/322345/85275

Comment: If you're not using phantom power, do you have to boost the signal a lot to get it loud enough? Failing that, you may have an electrical grounding issue (or worse a dodgy bit of kit). Try replacing your mic and soundcard temporarily to isolate the source of the noise.

Comment: What happens when you do connect phantom power? The noise goes away?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the infamous condenser microphone Neewer NW-800 (or thereabouts) or one of its relabelings.  Works with balanced and unbalanced connections and phantom power or plugin power, for a generous definition of "condenser microphone", "balanced" and "works".

There is really no point in throwing good money after the bad, so consider the following upgrade path: first get yourself a reasonably good USB (or even Firewire, your computer permitting) interface providing full phantom power on balanced XLR microphone inputs.  There are even numerous comparatively old ones with reasonable quality (and a few without reasonable quality, but their rate is lower among those with true +48V phantom power and balanced inputs).  There are even good ones with only line-level inputs but they are fairly esoteric and then you'd need to invest into separate microphone preamps, so it's easiest not to consider them.

With a good audio interface with +48V phantom power your NW-800 microphones will sound as good as they ever will.  Which is not a high bar to cross.  But at least you'll not think you missed an opportunity when you resell them and get actual condenser mics of reasonable quality (even something as cheap as Samson CO2 electret condensers will be in a different class than the NW-800, even though being in a separate class from intermediate or high quality mics).

Don't invest in a separate phantom power supply: they are either more garbage that you'll feel sorry having paid for, or they have a price tag that puts them in no useful relation to the kind of setup you are aiming for because basically any audio interface or preamp with microphone inputs (short of garbage level) from consumer to prosumer level will have phantom power built-in anyway.

Comment: "a generous definition of "condenser microphone", "balanced" and "works"." - gold!